# 7 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEpKa.png]

After updating to Xcode 8.3.1, I get this error when running my project.

Comment: Seems like you have imported / included the libraries twice? Check for Header Files, which import these and whether other header files do import the library headers, just as the other import-header

Comment: Your project settings are messed up. You seem to have desperately added loads of search paths, even some that do not exist. Post an example of a duplicated file (full path please).

Comment: You need remove the duplicate files from your project.\

Answer (score 0):

The error may occur when you copy and paste the contents of one file to another file with its interface name which means two classes with same interface name.

> In your code you have different files with the same Interface name.

Comment: Thanks for reply me,
But I was update the Xcode version at that time error on it. otherwise it's working fine not a any issue.